# Create a new With method with multiple value

Tags: java, lombok

I create a record like this (there are more field...)

```
@Builder
@With
public record DepotRecord(Long id, String x, String, y, String z, String a)
}
```

A part of the generated code will look

```
public DepotRecord withId(final Long id) {
    return this.id == id ? this : new DepotRecord(id, this.x, this.y,  this.z, this.a);
}
```

In rare case, i need to change more then one field.

Maybe there is a way to have something generated  who look like

```
public DepotRecord withIdXY(final Long id, String x, String y) {
    return this.id == id ? this : new DepotRecord(id, x, y, this.a);
}
```

Otherwise there a way to create a custom method?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the fields are independent of one another, you already have it.

```
myDepotRecord.withId(id).withX(x).withY(y)
```

and you can wrap that in a method if you like

```
public DepotRecord withIdXY(final Long id, String x, String y) {
  return myDepotRecord.withId(id).withX(x).withY(y);
}
```

In general, it's going to be better to give your API users the tools to compose together into whatever they want, rather than trying to anticipate every possible use case and provide a one-liner that does exactly that. What can you build more with? A big box of legos, or a pre-made lego house superglued together?

Comment: problem with this solutions it's you will recreate 3 times the record.

Comment: That's always the case with `@With`. But unless you know that's a problem (e.g. from profiling you app), that's almost certainly _not_ a problem.